# AT+CPMS "SM" Storage

Tags: sms, at-command, sim-card

AT+CPMS? query to a SIM returns

`+CPMS: "SM",0,60, "SM,0,60,"SM",0,60`

```
OK
```

The total storage is 60 messages maximum, and 0 are currently stored.
All messages are stored on the SIM.

An existing legacy application fails when trying to populate all 60 message boxes because message box 55 is the last successful write location.

When trying to populate the spaces 56-60, the command returns `CMS Error 322` which is a memory full error.

The text in each SMS is simply "P H" which is 3 ASCII bytes, so each text doesn't use an excessive amount of memory.

Has anyone an explanation why the spaces 56-60 are unavailable, although the CPMS? query shows them as available? Thanks.